# Ethers Js v6 vs v5

Tags: ethers.js, javascript

What is the current consensus on the stability of Ethers.js v6 for development, and are there any recommended reasons or scenarios where using Ethers.js v5 might be preferable over v6? 
Or is Ethers js v6 the way to go for future?

Comment: Another option would be Viem -> https://viem.sh/docs/introduction.html

Comment: use v5 since v6 is completely redesigned and completely breaks the interface.

source: trust me bro. I've been there. (I'll add v6 isn't ready and probably never will; it will be replaced by libs like viem)